# Extract the top-level directory in a URL in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I want to extract the top-level directory in a URL in Google Data Studio.

This is what it looks like now: `www.mydomain.com/folder/url-path`
And this is what it should looks like at the end: `/folder/url-path`

I've tried the recommendation from Data Studio Help, but this is not working on my site

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT( URL , '^https://[^/]+/([^/]+)/' )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no https:// in the example url, so you could make that part optional. Also the capture group only matches until the first `/` and you can add `[^/]*` after it to optionally match any char except a `/`

```
^(?:https?://)?[^/]+/([^/]+/[^/]*)
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4Sxlj/1/)

Comment: It is possible `^(?:https?://)?[^/]+/(.+)` will do.